# Prevent GeoWebCache from re-rendering tiles when the data is updated

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache

How can I prevent GeoWebCache from re-rendering the map tiles when the underlying data has changed?

There's a script which deletes the cache every X seconds. I want GeoWebCache to only re-render tiles when my script has deleted the cache. Currently, GeoWebCache does re-render when the cache has been cleared however it also re-renders when the data changes.

Comment: Are you doing WFS-T transactions against a GeoServer that's also hosting the GWC? Otherwise, I don't know how GWC would get to know the data has been modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the standalone GeoWebCache then you have full control over when it's cleared.

That said, unless you are pre-caching then it's probably not a good idea delaying the cache delete as any areas that weren't cached previously will render the tiles from the new data.

End result, you'll have tiles from the old data and new data side by side.